# Is there anything to check after your computer locks up or freezes?

Tags: freeze

I have a Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition laptop with Ubuntu 14.04, that has worked very well for over a year. However, recently I have been experiencing freezes where the machine does not respond to any keyboard or mouse events and I have to power it off. Is there anything to look at after you log back on after a freeze like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Look at `/var/log/kern.log`, and check the lines before the reboot (lines with `kernel: [    0.000000]` were logged 0.000000 seconds after the reboot, so look at the lines preceding that one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There are lines in there talking about the CPU core and package temperatures being above a threshold and the clock being throttled. I guess that could cause a freeze if the temperature remained high or went higher.

Comment: Yes, if your computer is overheating, it will stop. Find and fix the overheating problem before you kill your computer permanently.