# Server rebooting unexpectedly

Tags: 14.04, reboot, log

In the past month, I've noticed that our [Dell PowerEdge T630](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-t630/pd?~ck=anav) (*Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS*) server is rebooting unexpectedly (Jan 29 were manual reboots):

```
$cat /var/log/wtmp.report | grep boot | grep -v 'Jan 29'
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-77-generi Wed Feb 10 09:00 - 13:59  (04:58)
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-76-generi Wed Jan 27 09:01 - 10:47 (2+01:45)
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-74-generi Tue Jan 19 10:34 - 10:47 (10+00:13)
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-74-generi Wed Jan 13 09:02 - 10:47 (16+01:45)
```

So, of all the unspecified reboots, they all (*with the exception of Jan 19*) seem to be taking place every other Wednesday at around 9:00am (UTC-6).

I've looked through all the usual suspects (`/var/log/kern.log`, `/var/log/auth.log`, `/var/log/dmesg`, `/var/log/syslog`, etc), but can't find any sort of reason for the reboot.

I'm running [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) on the server; whenever I do a manual reboot, I'll get an automated email from Fail2ban saying SSH has been stopped, and then another email saying it has started back up.  Interestingly enough, when these unspecified reboots occur, I only get an email saying SSH has started back up (that is, I don't get one about SSH shutting down).

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this?  This server is only used by us, and certainly isn't being pushed to it's limits in any capacity.  The server is running a traditional ([Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/)) LAMP stack, along with SSH, and various other things like python and what not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there anything to check after your computer locks up or freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/728987/is-there-anything-to-check-after-your-computer-locks-up-or-freezes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that it was a power issue associated with our building.  The PSU which the serve was hooked up to was faulty and wasn't operating properly when the building would go through it's semi-weekly power flicker.  Anywho, buying a new PSU resolved the issue.